# Android Gradle running task before building

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I've got this task into build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'

task checkstyle(type: Checkstyle) {
    // Cleaning the old log because of the creation for the new ones
    delete fileTree(dir: "${project.rootDir}/app/build/reports")
    source 'src'
    include '**/*.java'
    exclude '**/gen/**'
    // empty classpath
    classpath = files()
    //Do not fail build
    ignoreFailures = false
}
```

I want this to run automatically when i try to build the app and if finds  errors to fail the build. I'm not sure how and where to call the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
project.afterEvaluate{
    assembleAcceptanceDebug.dependsOn("checkstyle")
}
```

This is what's finally worked. I found the task name when i click to run the app then the problem was that this task does not exists before Evaluate so that was the problem. Now it's working. Thank you and thanks to this https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-define-a-preprocessing-task-for-android-build/6147